# import QtPositioning in QML reports missing module, but it's not missing

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml

I'm trying to build a QML project in Visual Studio with CMake. Here are my files:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12 FATAL_ERROR)

project(MyProject)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Quick Core Network)
find_package(Qt5QuickCompiler)

qtquick_compiler_add_resources(RESOURCES qml.qrc)

add_executable(MyExec main.cpp ${RESOURCES})

qt5_use_modules(MyExec Quick Core Network)
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtPositioning 5.11

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

qml.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

When I build and run this, I get this:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:3 plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtPositioning": Cannot load library D:\Dev\MyProject\build\bin\qml\QtPositioning\declarative_positioningd.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

However, when I go to that directory, declarative_positioningd.dll is there. The only thing online I could find similar to this problem is [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/91746/impossibile-to-load-declarative_positioning-dll). They say they solved their problem via a missing Qt5PositioningQuick.dll file, but this file is also present in the relevant Qt5 install directories, and I also tried putting it in the folder with declarative_positioningd.dll to no avail.

This problem is specific to QtPositioning, other QML imports I've tried seem to work fine (other than QtLocation, which depends on QtPositioning).

Comment: There was a [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50227) causing this kind of error in Qt 5.5. You can try their work-around suggested in that thread, to manually add the path to the libraries in your `Path` environment variable. Or try a different version of Qt. Hopefully one of those helps!

Comment: @squareskittles I'm on Qt 5.12, but I'll give it a try anyway when I get back to work Monday. Thanks.